# Byte array to int getting weird int result

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I know there are many similar questions in here, but I have some weird case. What I want to do is to convert a `byte[4]` to an int.

Here is the conversion from int to byte:

```
int data24bit = 51;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    data8bit = (byte)(data24bit & 0x0000FF);
    data24bit = data24bit >> 8;
    byte_file.put(data8bit);
}
```

So far is clear enough. After that I want to read this 4 bytes to get the 51 back. I tried to do it by different ways:

Reading 4 bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    byte b = dis.readByte();
     bytes[i] = b;
}
// bytes[3] = (byte)(0x000000);
```

Convert bytes to int:

```
int value = 0;
value = ((0xFF & bytes[0]) << 24) | ((0xFF & bytes[1]) << 16) |
    ((0xFF & bytes[2]) << 8) | (0xFF & bytes[3]);
```

or

```
value = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt();
```

or

```
value = new BigInteger(bytes).intValue();
```

I always get `855638016` as result where `51` is expected.

When I debug the code and look into the byte array I can see the following content: `[51, 0, 0, 0]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "`for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {`" Are you intentionally not handling the 4th byte?

Comment: Yes, because the conversion code uses only the first 3 bytes. I mean it doesn't come from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're writing the bytes in little-endian (least significant byte first), but read it back assuming big-endian.

After writing it out, your byte array looks like this:

```
[51, 0, 0, 0]
```

Then you're trying to convert that back into an integer, like in this example from your post:

```
value =   ((0xFF & bytes[0]) << 24)
        | ((0xFF & bytes[1]) << 16)
        | ((0xFF & bytes[2]) << 8)
        | (0xFF & bytes[3]);
```

If you fill in the actual values, that calculation is basically this:

```
value =  51 * 256 * 256 * 256
        + 0 * 256 * 256
        + 0 * 256
        + 0
      = 855638016
```

While what you actually want is this:

```
value =  0 * 256 * 256 * 256
       + 0 * 256 * 256
       + 0 * 256
       + 51
      = 51
```

The fixed calculation would thus be this:

```
value =   ((0xFF & bytes[3]) << 24)
        | ((0xFF & bytes[2]) << 16)
        | ((0xFF & bytes[1]) << 8)
        | (0xFF & bytes[0]);
```

Comment: Yes, thx, I already discovered this. Posted my own answer also.

Answer (score 0):

Ok stupid enough but I just didn't preserve the byte order.

```
[51, 0, 0, 0] -> is 855638016
[0, 0, 0, 51] -> is 51
```